# Execute code inside batch opened terminal

Tags: batch-file, kdb, startupscript

I’m writing a startup script for a kdb process (but I don’t think the type of process matters, could just as easily be python). I want the script to run my q file, and then inside the terminal, execute a line (myfunc[], for example).
Trying the -c batch command gives “The system cannot find the file specified”.
Any advice? Thanks.
Code I am currently trying:

```
 cmd /k “q myqfile.q” -c “myfunc[]”
```

Comment: Perhaps provide the full path?  something like `cmd /k "c:\q\q c:\q\files\myqfile.q -c myfunc[]"`  But your additional problem might be using multiple double quotes.  Might I suggest a batch file called, let's say, `runq.cmd` with the command `"c:\path to q\q" "c:\path to q file\myqfile.q" -c "myfunc[]"`, then you would `cmd /c "c:\path to runq\runq.cmd"`.  Though one has to wonder if you even need the `cmd /c` part anyway.

Comment: Please note that when you create your batch-file/command, not to use smart/curly quotes, **`“`**, and **`”`**, as you have in your question, but standard/straight ones, **`"`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd /k "copy myqfile.q myqfile_.q & echo myfunc[] >> myqfile_.q & q myqfile_.q & del myqfile_.q"
```

I create a copy of myqfile.q, then append myfunc[] to the copy, then run the copy, and finally delete the copy.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This works perfectly...but as Nico said, can you add some explanation? Thank you

Comment: @PythonParka OK, I'll explain, see above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact it is q does matter here. I don't think you can pass a command to kdb/q like that. Add this to the bottom of myqfile.q:

```
myfunc[];
exit 0
```

Comment: This is what I was doing initially, but I’d like to be able to run it as stated in the question if possible. Could be the case that you can’t do it with q - I figured it was a generic way of passing commands to a terminal. I may have to go back to this method

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the command line but I don't know if it's best practice:

```
$ cat script.q
a:1;
func:{show a+x};
$ export QHOME=/opt/q && echo 'func[10]' | $QHOME/l64/q script.q
11
$
```